# deleting consequtive integers with regEx

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

How do I replace the occurence of three consequtive integers?

I have a list that is containing some unwanted integers that are all three numbers combined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this regex will look for 3 consecutive numbers using a quantifier:

```
[0-9]{3}
```

The regex engine of Notepad++ 5.9.8 and lower does not support quantifiers ([source](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs/3245/)).

Comment: Do i need to edit your code using notepad++ find field? because its not working using that exact code

Comment: you will have to click the 'regex expression' radio button on the bottom left of the find window

Comment: I did do that still nothing

Comment: @DinoExcel leave out the slashes

Comment: @JustinGingyMcDonald those slashes are not relevant to the regex and only a literal artifact used by a few programming languages

Comment: what is this you are posting? its not working. WIth or without slashes.

Answer (score 1):

```
Find   :([^\d])\d{3}([^\d])
Replace:\1\2
```

This will turn...

> |333|4444|55555| "1","22","333"
>
> ...to....
>
> ||4444|55555| "1","22",""